# iOS 6 navigation - do I have to use storyboards?

Tags: xcode, uikit, storyboard, ios6

I have an app that is working fine for iOS 5, I've just installed the iOS 6 simulator and my navigation is no longer working at all.  Also my viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods are no longer firing.

I'm using [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]; to navigate.  Do I have to use StoryBoards to navigate in iOS 6?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, Storyboards are optional and have been around since iOS 5.0. If your navigation is broken it'll be due to errors in your code.

Comment: More often than not the newer versions of the frameworks enforce the rules defined in earlier versions in a more strict way. Often behaviour you expected was not actually supported and only worked coincidentally. Revisit your implementation, re read some documentation and it'll make sense. Alternatively - update your question with a specific issue ;)